# Azure DevOps NexusIQ task 'Error from CLI Command failed with exit code 1: java -jar'

Tags: java, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sonatype, nexus-iq

## What do I want to accomplish?

'*Hello to the incredible community of StackOverflow*'

Scan the **packages** of our code with **NexusIQ Task**, in an **Azure DevOps Services Pipeline**

### Environment

1. **Azure DevOps Services**-->Pipelines-->Task-->**NexusIQ**
2. **NexusIQ Task Parameter(s)**:

- **Service Connection** = Stablished and whitelisted
- **Scan Targets** = `**/*.jar, **/*.war, **/*.ear, **/*.zip, **/*.tar.gz, **/*.dll`

### Error output

Performing the **Scan** of our code the last bit throws the next error:

`Error from CLI: Error: Command failed with exit code 1: java -jar`

### Error log detailed

`Error from CLI: Error: Command failed with exit code 1: java -jar F:\AzureAgents\Agent01\_work\_tasks\NexusIqPipelineTask_4f40d1a2-83b0-4ddc-9a77-e7f279eb1802\1.3.19\resources\nexus-iq-cli-1.128.0-01.jar @F:\AzureAgents\Agent01\_work\_tasks\NexusIqPipelineTask_4f40d1a2-83b0-4ddc-9a77-e7f279eb1802\1.3.19\resources\cli-params.txt`

### Troubleshooting details

- I did test changing the **Scan Tartget** from `**/*.jar, **/*.war, **/*.ear, **/*.zip, **/*.tar.gz, **/*.dll` to `**/*.war, **/*.ear, **/*.zip, **/*.tar.gz, **/*.dll`
- As can be seen above the `**/*.jar` **file extension** was removed but either way the error output remains the same:

`Error from CLI: Error: Command failed with exit code 1: java -jar F:\AzureServicesAgents\AgentU01\_work\_tasks\NexusIqPipelineTask_4f40d1a2-83b0-4ddc-9a77-e7f279eb1802\1.3.21\resources\nexus-iq-cli-1.128.0-01.jar @F:\AzureServicesAgents\AgentU01\_work\_tasks\NexusIqPipelineTask_4f40d1a2-83b0-4ddc-9a77-e7f279eb1802\1.3.21\resources\cli-params.txt`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi @Emmac, yes, I did update the java version in our testing server to 14, that solved the issue, hope this helps you as well

Comment: Thanks Alexis. This was what worked for me also to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution for this threat

We performed an update of the **java version** in our testing server to **version 14**, which solved the issue, hope this helps you all the community as well